# Back Press Force Close

Tags: java, android

- I have Used Pick Contacts functionality in my Activity.Its working fine to pick contact and other details info like Name.
- But when i click button it goes for contact intent and shows number all is well.
- But if i didn't select number and clicking back press means the app getting force close.

**Code**

```
Intent inten = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(inten,PICK_CONTACT);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    Cursor c;
    switch (reqCode) {
    case (PICK_CONTACT):

        Uri result = data.getData();
    Log.v("TAG", "Got a result: " + result.toString());

    // get the contact id from the Uri
    String id = result.getLastPathSegment();

    // query for phone numbers for the selected contact id
    c = getContentResolver().query(
            Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
            Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
            new String[]{id}, null);

    int phoneIdx = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
    int phoneType = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE);

    if(c.getCount() > 1) { // contact has multiple phone numbers
        final CharSequence[] numbers = new CharSequence[c.getCount()];
        int i=0;
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            while(!c.isAfterLast()) { // for each phone number, add it to the numbers array
                String type = (String) Phone.getTypeLabel(this.getResources(), c.getInt(phoneType), ""); // insert a type string in front of the number
                String number = type + ": " + c.getString(phoneIdx);
                numbers[i++] = number;
                c.moveToNext();
            }
            // build and show a simple dialog that allows the user to select a number
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Select Number");
            builder.setItems(numbers, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    String number = (String) numbers[item];
                    int index = number.indexOf(":");
                    number = number.substring(index + 2);
                    cNumber=number;
                    edt.setText(cNumber);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // loadContactInfo(number); // do something with the selected number
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.setOwnerActivity(this);
            alert.show();

        } else Log.w("TAG", "No results");
    } else if(c.getCount() == 1) {
        // contact has a single phone number, so there's no need to display a second dialog

        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            cNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("data1"));
            edt.setText(cNumber);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    break;
    }

}
```

In my activity i have written back press also...

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    btnflag++;
    if(btnflag==1)
    {
        Intent mainscr = new Intent(FindList1.this, MainScreen.class);
        startActivity(mainscr);
        btnflag=0;
        finish();
    }
}
```

But Unfortunately the crash has happened.....

Comment: Post the logcat please.

Comment: You need to look at the result code. It should be obvious that the request code will always be the same. You're processing your code regardless of whether the user selected a contact or not.

Comment: well I can tell you one thing, you are not checking the result code so if it returns anything other than `RESULT_OK` it will probably crash

Comment: Yup. `data` is probably null. Or if `data` is not null then `result` will be.

Comment: tyczj is right. Since you aren't checking the result for OK, you are assuming that a contact got picked. You will get null pointer when you try to call methods on `result` object.

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicked back button it will call on activityResult(). I guess your getting null pointer exception in this code.

```
Uri result = data.getData();
Log.v("TAG", "Got a result: " + result.toString());

// get the contact id from the Uri
String id = result.getLastPathSegment();

// query for phone numbers for the selected contact id
c = getContentResolver().query(
Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
new String[]{id}, null);

int phoneIdx = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
int phoneType = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE);
```

data.getData() it will returns null. Because your not selected any contact and your pressed back button in Contacts activity.

`if(data==null){
return;
}`

and handle the exception

onBackPressed() method will call when current activity is pressed back button. It will not called when your in other activity.